# AES key generation in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, aes

Currently I am working in generating a key for AES encryption/decryption. The key is based on a password an a random salt per user. My first idea was to made a SecretKeyFactory with the algorithm "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1". The problem is that Android currently does not support it.

Doing some search I found the answer from erickson recommended the use of that algorithm for the same purpose ([AES 256 bit encryption](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:4T7m9QGHPt8J:stackoverflow.com/questions/992019/java-256bit-aes-encryption+SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(%22PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1%22)&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&source=www.google.com)). My question is how diffent would be the encryption process if I use "PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC" instead of having "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1"? There are any other idea of how to generate a key for AES in android in a secure way and not not just hashing the password with the salt fro the key (I don't think that approach to follow).

Comment: Note that PBKDF2 does exactly that: hashing the salt with the password using a HMAC. It just does it numerous times, which makes bruteforcing more expensive.

Answer (score 1):

As the name says, "PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC" will use SHA256 as HMAC, instead if using SHA1. Because this is a different algorithm, it will generate a different Key for the chosen password.

If you en/decrypt only on android, this should be fine.

Comment: I had the same problem, but in my case I had to decrypt something previously encrypted in PHP with mcrypt. I still have no idea what settings to use on android for AES256, PBKDF2(SHA1), PKCS#5padding. I couldn't find documentation anywhere on what crypto instance does what (although I managed to generate a list of supported instances). I ended up writing my own PBKDF2 implementation and set the key manually, then using ciphermode "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding". Unfortunately, this only seems to support AES128.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext) throws Exception {
               byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes("UTF-16"));
               byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes("UTF-16"));
               return toHex(result);
       }
       
       public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted) throws Exception {
               byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes("UTF-16"));
               byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);
               byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
               return new String(result);
              }

       private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
               KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
               SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
               sr.setSeed(seed);
           kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
           SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
           byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
           return raw;
       }

       
       private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
           SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
               Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
           cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
           byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
               return encrypted;
       }

       private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
           SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
               Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
           cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
           byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
               return decrypted;
       }

       public static String toHex(String txt) {
               return toHex(txt.getBytes());
       }
       public static String fromHex(String hex) {
               return new String(toByte(hex));
       }
       
       public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
               int len = hexString.length()/2;
               byte[] result = new byte[len];
               for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                       result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16).byteValue();
               return result;
       }

       public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
               if (buf == null)
                       return "";
               StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2*buf.length);
               for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
                       appendHex(result, buf[i]);
               }
               return result.toString();
       }
       private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";
       private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
               sb.append(HEX.charAt((b>>4)&0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b&0x0f));
       }
```

Comment: Never use `new String(...)` without specifying the encoding. Also, using the password directly as a seed does not seem to be the best idea (as it does not make brute-forcing hard). And you are doing superfluous mapping from key to bytes to key again.

Comment: Deriving key material from a password using a random number generator directly should be avoided. A proper key stretching algorithm should be used instead such as [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2).