# Android - Encrypt Multiple Files Based on listFiles?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, encryption

As a school project, I'm trying to achieve the following:
-List all files (pictures) in a folder.
Go through every picture one by one and password encrypt them using AES.

This is meant as an application to safely encrypt pictures, making only You able to decrypt and view them - provided you have the right password.

So far I am able to get all file names in the folder/directory, and encrypt only one specified file. The problem is, that I don't know how to go through the list, and encrypt all the files to the end.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
package com.example.secretpictures;
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;


import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;

import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;

import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class EncryptService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = EncryptService.class.getSimpleName();
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;



}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();

Log.d(TAG, "OnCreate");
}


@SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

Log.d(TAG, "OnStart");

File file[] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();
recursiveFileFind(file);


try {

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/mnt/sdcard/secretpictures/yolo.png");
// This stream write the encrypted text. This stream will be wrapped by another stream.
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/secretpictures/yolo2.enc");

// Length is 16 byte
SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec("MyDifficultPassw".getBytes(), "AES");
// Create cipher
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks);
    // Wrap the output stream
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
    // Write bytes
    int b;
    byte[] d = new byte[8];
    while((b = fis.read(d)) != -1) {
        cos.write(d, 0, b);
    }
    // Flush and close streams.
    cos.flush();
    cos.close();
    fis.close();


} catch (IOException  e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();

Log.d(TAG, "OnDestroy");
}



public void recursiveFileFind(File[] file1){
int i = 0;
String filePath="";
 if(file1!=null){
while(i!=file1.length){
    filePath = file1[i].getAbsolutePath();
        if(file1[i].isDirectory()){
                File file[] = file1[i].listFiles();
            recursiveFileFind(file);
            }
        i++;
        Log.d(i+"", filePath);

}
}
}   
}
```

As you see, it's very ugly coded, but get's the job done for now.
This service is called when the mainactivity is created.

This line specifies the file to be encrypted:  `FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/mnt/sdcard/secretpictures/yolo.png");`

How would one approach getting the inputstream to go through `File file[] = file1[i].listFiles();` to encrypt every and all of the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have a `File` object as shown in your code that finds files you can obtain a `FileInputStream` for that file using the constructor [`FileInputStream(File)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileInputStream.html#FileInputStream%28java.io.File%29).

Some notes on your crypto system. It isn't very secure. In no particular order

- You use a UTF-8 bytes directly without a salt for you key material. Use a key stretching
  algorithm like [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) and feed the password bytes to it with a salt. You can store the salt as plaintext with the encrypted image.
- You're using the default cipher spec for `AES`. This expands to `AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding`. `ECB` is not a secure mode for your encrypting more than 1 block of plaintext (16 bytes for AES). ECB fails to hide patterns in the plaintext due to the fact that the same input plaintext results in the same output ciphertext. Images are particularly vulnerable to this due to repeating patterns. See this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29) for more info on ECB, it also gives an encrypted image as an example. Most other modes you can use (CBC, CTR, etc) required an IV, the IV should be randomly generated and you can store it in the clear with the encrypted image.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I was looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277533/aes-key-generation-in-android
It seems to do the job. If the look at the mentioned code, would changing the cleartext string to input the "file" work?
I'll give it a try.

Comment: @MattDeVenge You do not want to use a password to seed a random number generator. The proper way to to create key material from a password is using a key stretching algorithm. Aside from that, Android recently changed its implementation of secure random and a given seed no longer gives you a deterministic random sequence. Use a `SecretKeyFactory` like so `SecretKeyFactory
                    .getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1")`